# Pycharm Console - Virtual Environment

Tags: console, pycharm, environment

I just want to: `import numpy as np` 
from my Pycharm console.

I have set up virtual environments.
I can: `import numpy as np` in my `.py` code in my projects.

Is there a way to point my console to a virtual environment?

I know I was able to `import numpy as np` from my console in the past.  I do not know how I broke this or how to fix it.

Comment: Make sure correct interpreter is selected in **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Python Console**.

Comment: This what my screen looks like ... Project: Keras01    Python Interpreter: Python 3.6 (Keras01).  All my programs under the Keras01 project can import numpy ... but I cannot import numpy on the console